# Relationships not saved with Microservices

Tags: microservices, jhipster, jdl

I've been struggling to get my relationships to be saved when I converted my application from a monolith to microservices.  I can update them via the webapp but on refresh or viewing the database the change is not visible.  Basically nothing happens even though the toast indicates that the edit was successful.  I don't see any errors nor warnings in either the gateway and nor microservice logs.

The PUT update calls do have the selected owned entities:

```
organisation: {
    "id": "f43d61b1-3ba5-4891-a252-a5e0d73e4bbc",
    "name": "Nevada Wooden Principal",
    "status": "synergize transmit Hybrid",
    "location": "interactive incremental",
    "headcount": 7182,
    "parent": {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "status": null,
        "location": null,
        "headcount": null,
        "parentId": null
    },
    "parentId": null
}
organisationId: null,
personalInfo: {
    "id": "0b76be08-4cbf-408d-ab03-3ba9a3add15d",
    "dateOfBirth": "2023-07-11",
    "network": "Bicycle Uranium Integration",
    "wallet": null
},
personalInfoId: null
```

But the GET read calls of the owner entity still have:

```
organisation: {
    "id": null,
    "name": null,
    "status": null,
    "location": null,
    "headcount": null,
    "parentId": null
},
organisationId: null,
personalInfo: {
    "id": null,
    "dateOfBirth": null,
    "network": null,
    "wallet": null
}
personalInfoId: null
```

I have tried with jhipster 7.9.3 , v7.x_maintenance, 8.0.0-beta.1, and latest version from main. But I did not find a similar bug being reported so I must be doing something wrong.

To get relationships to save for the monolith, I had to ensure I defined ids the same way for all my entities (id UUID).  I tried this for microservices, and also relying on the default ids in all cases.

To get the application to generate and run correctly with microservices and the latest version of 8.0 I had to change from jwt default to ouath2 and from vue to react.

Here is my simplified jdl file:

```
application {
  config {
    applicationType gateway
    authenticationType oauth2
    baseName mynk
    buildTool gradle
    clientFramework react
    clientTheme zephyr
    devDatabaseType h2Memory
    languages [en, fr]
    nativeLanguage en
    packageName ma.mynk.wallet
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    serviceDiscoveryType consul
  }
  entities *
}

application {
  config {
    applicationType microservice
    authenticationType oauth2
    baseName walletService
    buildTool gradle
    devDatabaseType h2Memory
    packageName ma.mynk.wallet.core
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    serviceDiscoveryType consul
  }
  entities *
}

entity Wallet {
  id UUID
  phoneNumber String
  tag String 
  firstName String 
  lastName String 
  email String
  currency String 
  contractId String 
}

entity PersonalInfo {
  id UUID
  dateOfBirth LocalDate
  network String
}

entity Organisation {
  id UUID
  name String 
  status String 
  location String 
  headcount Integer
}

relationship OneToOne {
  Wallet{personalInfo} to PersonalInfo
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  Organisation{parent(name)} to Organisation
  Wallet{organisation(name)} to Organisation
}

service * with serviceImpl
paginate * with pagination
```

I generate the application as follows:
`jhipster jdl --skip-jhipster-dependencies --workspaces --monorepository ../docs/jdl/relationship.jdl`

To run everything:

```
docker compose -f src/main/docker/consul.yml up -d
docker compose -f src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up -d
```

and then `./gradlew` under each microservice.

Comment: It looks like I was missing the microservices directive:
`microservice * with walletService`

I now have some new issues when running the microservice.  Will report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was indeed missing the `microservice` directive:
`microservice * with walletService`

I had read somewhere that it would be auto generated by listing the entities as part of the application (`entities *`) but I must have misunderstood that.